# Bulk insert/update from Json param in Postgresql using ON CONFLICT (Id), but Id property must be acquired within the function as not included in param

Tags: postgresql

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public."FeatureToggles"
(
  "Id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
  "IsDeleted" boolean NOT NULL,
  "IsImported" boolean NOT NULL,
  "TextProp" character varying(35),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_FeatureToggles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)

CREATE TABLE public."Additions"
(
  "Id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
  "FeatureToggleId" int NOT NULL,
  "IsDeleted" boolean NOT NULL,
  "Url" character varying(35) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_FeatureToggles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
  CONSTRAINT "FK_Additions_FeatureToggles_FeatureToggleId" FOREIGN KEY ("FeatureToggleId")
    REFERENCES public."FeatureToggles" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
```

Insert one record into table:

```
INSERT INTO public."FeatureToggles" ("IsDeleted", "TextProp", "IsImported") VALUES(false, 'X', true);
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunctionname(jsonparam json)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

  INSERT INTO "FeatureToggles" ("Id", "IsDeleted", "IsImported", "TextProp")
    SELECT (COALESCE(SELECT "Id" FROM "FeatureToggles" WHERE "TextProp" = (prop->>'TextProp')::character varying(35)), 0),  
        (prop->>'IsDeleted')::boolean,
        true, 
        (prop->>'TextProp')::character varying(35)
    json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop      
        
  ON CONFLICT ("Id") DO
  UPDATE SET
    "IsDeleted" = EXCLUDED."IsDeleted"

  INSERT INTO "Additions" ("FeatureToggleId", "IsDeleted", "Url")
    SELECT (SELECT "Id" FROM "FeatureToggles" WHERE "TextProp" = (prop->>'TextProp')::character varying(35)),  
        (prop->>'IsDeleted')::boolean, 
        (prop->>'Additions')::character varying(35)
    json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop

  DELETE FROM "FeatureToggles" WHERE "IsImported" = true AND "TextProp" IS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT (prop->>'TextProp')::character varying(35)szi
    json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop)
    
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
```

Sample `JSON`:

```
[
  {
    "IsDeleted": true,
    "TextProp": "X",
    "Additions": 
      [
        "Test1",
        "Test2"
      ]
  },
  {
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "TextProp": "Y",
    "Additions": 
      [
        "Test3",
        "Test4"
      ]
  }
]
```

Calling the function with this `JSON` param should update the one and only row in the `FeatureToggles` table to `IsDeleted` true and insert a new row into the `FeatureToggles` table with `Id` equals to 2, `IsDeleted` false and `TextProp` is Y. Also it should insert all `Additions` given in the `JSON` param into the corresponding table and with the correct foreign keys.

I ran into problems with populating the `Id` properties from the existing table and also inserting `Additions` into the other table.

It would be a great if the function would delete any rows in the `FeatureToggle` and the corresponding `Additions` table too if it does exists in table already, `IsImported` property is true, but is not in the `JSON` param.

Example if we change the insert script to:

```
INSERT INTO public."FeatureToggles" ("IsDeleted", "TextProp", "IsImported") VALUES(false, 'X', true);
INSERT INTO public."FeatureToggles" ("IsDeleted", "TextProp", "IsImported") VALUES(false, 'X222', true);
```

After calling the function with the same `JSON` param, the row with X222 should be deleted because it is marked as imported, but has no matching item (matched by `TextProp` property) within the new param list.

Any help would be much appreciated as this function needs to handle tens of thousands of records as parameter on each call.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have `nvarchar` data type ! are you sure this is postgresql? `varchar` in postgrsql already supports unicode

Comment: also those insert inot .. select .. statement inside the functions doesn't look they will compile at all

Comment: that is why I am asking for help..

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: guys all string properties are just normal texts. I only wrote the type from the top of my head and it is irrelevant to the issue I am facing. None of the tables will store JSON data as only the parameter is a JSON type which should be converted as detailed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your function (and your DDL)

Most importantly, `json_array_elements()` is a set returning function, so you need a `FROM` clause in order to generate multiple rows.

You also need to terminate each SQL statement in the function with `;` and `IS NOT IN` is invalid - you need `NOT IN`

So the function should be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunctionname(jsonparam json)
 RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

  INSERT INTO "FeatureToggles" ("Id", "IsDeleted", "IsImported", "TextProp")
  SELECT coalesce(ft."Id", 0),  
         (prop->>'IsDeleted')::boolean,
         true, 
         prop->>'TextProp'
  FROM json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop 
    LEFT JOIN "FeatureToggles" ft on ft."TextProp" = (prop->>'TextProp')
  ON CONFLICT ("Id") DO
  UPDATE SET
    "IsDeleted" = EXCLUDED."IsDeleted";

  INSERT INTO "Additions" ("FeatureToggleId", "IsDeleted", "Url")
  SELECT coalesce(ft."Id", 0),  
         (prop->>'IsDeleted')::boolean,
         prop->>'Additions'
  FROM json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop 
    JOIN "FeatureToggles" ft on ft."TextProp" = (prop->>'TextProp');

  DELETE FROM "FeatureToggles" 
  WHERE "IsImported" = true 
    AND "TextProp" NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT prop->>'TextProp' szi
                           FROM json_array_elements(jsonparam) prop);
    
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Note that `->>` returns a `text` value, so there is no need to cast the result of those expression if the target column is `text` or `varchar`.

I also changed the scalar sub-queries to JOINs. The first insert is equivalent to an outer join - although I think that is wrong (but that's what your current code tries to do). Because if the join doesn't return anything, the INSERT will try to create a row with `"Id" = 0` - bypassing the sequence generation. Using `on conflict()` with an auto-generated ID rarely makes sense. Maybe you want a unique index on `TextProp`?

I would probably implement that as a procedure rather than a function though.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cf9beba78a94c9f6ab2d580e09f76768)

Comment: As you pointed out `"Id" = 0` does not make any sense. What could I use as a workaround? Unfortunately unique index on `TextProp` is not an option as this property is null on all not imported rows. `ON CONFLICT` might not even work in this situation as you mentioned because if a row exists with the matching `TextProp` than it should be updated, if not match found an insert should be used with an auto generated `Id`. `TextProp` is unique for imported members only therefore a constraint cannot be applied.

Comment: Not sure if loading everything into a temp table first then populating the `Id` properties of the temp table using existing rows and lasty an if else (`Id IS NULL`) would be an efficient solution?